# How do you get Haskell to check SQL at compile time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell, hasql

I know it can be done, but I'm having trouble getting it working. I'm still finding my feet with Haskell.

I tried using postgresql-typed, but it wouldn't compile. They don't enable the QuasiQuotes extension, so I don't understand how their code would ever compile. It also fails with an error on the `useTPGDatabase` statement. I cloned the library's source code from Github, but their tests failed to compile using stack with exactly the same errors.

I considered using hasql-th, but it's not on stackage.org, which immediately puts it in the "too hard basket.". I considered switching to nix but that seems like even more effort.

Does somebody have a reliable recipe for getting an environment working that type-checks SQL at compile time in Haskell?

Comment: I believe `postgresql-simple` is pretty popular. Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I love using Selda and suggest you give it a go.

Comment: I'm currently using postgresql-simple, but I want to upgrade to something that checks my SQL at compile time - or better, using haskell-language-server on VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

> I considered using hasql-th, but it's not on stackage.org, which immediately puts it in the "too hard basket."

All you need to do is add the latest version of `hasql-th` to the `extra-deps` section of your `stack.yaml` file and all other deps that Stack will suggest to you when you build.

In the end your `stack.yaml` file should look something like this:

```
resolver: lts-17.9
extra-deps:
  - hasql-th-0.4.0.8
  - headed-megaparsec-0.1.0.4
  - postgresql-syntax-0.3.0.3
```

Anticipating a question in the spirit of "Why is it not listed on Stackage?" It's just that nobody has gotten to list these packages yet.

Comment: From the author himself! Thanks!

Comment: No wonder. I am subscribed to the "hasql" tag :) Cheers!